# Очень странная ситуация с функцией Javascript Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

есть переменная, которая вынесена за функцию

```
var relsi;
```

и вот если переменная равна `1`, то функция выполняет одни действия,
если переменная равна `2`, то другие действия.
и проблема в том, что выполнив одни действия, она перенаправляет на другую функцию, которая меняет значение `relsi` и запускует таймер для выполнения других действий `setTimeout` , но в итоге таймер не срабатывает и данное действие выполняется сразу.

```
    function mybackpack() {
    save = [];
    var name = [];
    var item_id = [];
    backpack = [];


    var url = 'google.com';
    request(url, function(err, res, body){
  if(err){console.log(err);}
  else{ 

            неважно что тут
   });

    if(Relsi === 1) {
    fs.writeFileSync('./app/data.json', JSON.stringify(backpack, null, 
  4));
    StartSell()
  }
  if(Relsi === 2) {
    CreateOrders()
 }
    };
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1 (телепатический).

Потому что Вы поставили круглые скобки после названия функции, пытаясь подать ссылку на нее в `setTimeout`.

Вариант 2 (решение в лоб).

Потому что в Вашем коде, к моменту проверки условия в втором `if`, функция, вызванная в первом `if` уже изменила значение переменной.

```
if(Relsi === 1) {
  ...
} else if (Relsi === 2) {
  ...
}
```

или

```
var localRelsi = Relsi;

if(localRelsi === 1) {
  ...
} 

if (localRelsi === 2) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: setTimeout(function () { mybackpack();  }, 1000 * 60 * 45)
не правильно ?

Comment: это что? зачем?

Comment: смотри у меня идет такая функция
function some() {
relsi = 2;
setTimeout(function () { mybackpack(); }, 1000 * 60 * 45);
}

но функция выполняется сразу же , не ждет 45 минут
учитывай то, что я уже вызывал эту функцию (mybackpack()) с значением relsi = 1;

Comment: Поставьте `else` перед вторым `if`.

Comment: спасибо вроде помогло, а почему это так работает? я логику не пойму; по идее и так должен был нормально выполняться

Comment: Потому что в Вашем коде, к моменту проверки условия в втором `if`, функция, вызванная в первом `if` уже изменила значение переменной.